# Problema con la configuracion de PHP

Tags: php

Hola tengo un problema con la configuración de php , y no entiendo por que.. ya Configure el PATH [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido.... y vas a tener que darnos más información del problema para saber de qué se trata así que edita la pregunta y coloca más información pertinente, si no es mucho pedir

Comment: Hola dany, pq eliminaste la pregunta de la matriz si tenías dudas yo podía explicarte, reconsidera lo que hiciste esa pregunta tal vez sea la duda de otros

Comment: Dany, volviste a cerrar la pregunta, ya el error se iba a solucionar, mi tiempo se respeta así que ahora búscate a otro que te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Segun lo que veo es un problema de formato. En JSON, debes escapar los backslash `\` escribiendolos como `\\`:

```
"c:\\xamp\\php\\php.exe "
```

ya que existen algunos caracteres de escape que comienzan con `\`, como por ejemplo para describir valores hexadecimales (ejemplo `\x0d`) y el interprete espera otra cosa.

**EDIT:**

Ademas, se ve en la ultima entrada del objeto no debe haber una coma, ya que esperaria un nuevo elemento. Quita esa coma para que el JSON sea valido.

Comment: Ya realice lo que me dijiste , y todo sigue igual!

Comment: Quiza debas agregar mas informacion de cual es el problema puntual, mensajes de error, y describir "que" es lo que esta mal o sigue igual. Agregué algo que puede estar fallando segun lo que veo de la imagen